# Is there a way of displaying the IP address of a comment in a view?

Tags: 7, views, comments

I have created a view to help me manage spam. Its main shortcoming that it does not display the IP address the comment came from.

Is there a way to obtain the IP address the comment came from?

When I go through the fields available to add to the view I can't see any field which contains the IP address.

Comment: Maybe try this module or their approach: https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_ip